# Ionic APK : App cannot be installed

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, gulp, bower

I just finished building an ionic app, it runs fine with ionic serve -l, infact it builds fine on another machine except this one new machine I am using to continue the project.

When I do ionic build android the build process runs fine and my apk is generated with the following output

```
 ionic build android
    Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\www\XXX\XXXX\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\www\XXX\XXX
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\www\XXX\XXX\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_79
Running: C:\www\XXX\XXX\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\www\XXX\XXX\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug
:dexDebug
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug
:zipalignDebug
:assembleDebug
:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 2.376 secs
    Built the following apk(s):
    C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
```

On trying to install the APK on the device I get App Cannot be install/Install Unsuccessful, but taking the APK from the other machine or generating(ionic build android) from the first machine works fine on the device.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure to uninstall the app from the device before installing?

Comment: The app has been uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

Look, your build ran just fine. Problem might be with your device not being recognized in adb.

In that case execute the command: adb devices, to see whether your phone is listed or not.

If it was not listed execute:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and try again... That worked for me.

Another possible reason can be that your phone is not set up to allow apps from unknown sources.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you using jdk7, please try jdk8.

Don't forget to add your new java jdk to your environment variables.

Please check these steps if there something missing.

**I. Development  environment  dependencies**

1)You need at Least to download a java JDK 8

2)Download an Android SDK manager

3)you must Add them to the environment variables

(Windows)

i)Open environment variables

ii)ANDROID_HOME:create a new user variable with name ANDROID_HOME and add the path of the SDK manager 
ex.C:\xxx\Android\sdk

iii)edit the user variable PATH value and add to it platform tools path ex. C:\xxx\Android\sdk\platform-tools

iV)JAVA_HOME:Don't forget also to edit in the user variable PATH, your old JAVA_HOME env path with the new JDK Path . ex.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

4)Globally install ionic and cordova

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

**II. Ionic CLI for build android**

5)`ionic cordova platform add android`

6)`ionic cordova build android`

**N.B:** there sometimes logging in issue through CLI when using this command, the next steps doesn't really make sense but it worked for me.

```
ionic config set backend pro -g
```

Retry the build process again ,if Still there a problem change to legacy and Then again back to pro

```
ionic config set backend legacy -g

ionic config set backend pro -g
```

It should work now, retry the build process again.

If still there a problem then make an app through the website of ionic
use this command with  the --pro-id  of your app and retry again.

```
ionic start --pro-id <ID>
```